# VBS script to copy file and then copy filepath and filename to clipboard

Tags: vbscript, copy, filenames, paste, filepath

I am trying to find a script that will let me right-click on a file in XP (or 7) and then choose and option (like "Copy to MyServer").

That would copy the file to the set location, and then it would then copy the filepath and name of the file to the clipboard so that I could paste that location into something else. (I want to paste it into my helpdesk ticket that only accepts URLs for pictures.)

So essentially this would let me copy a picture on my computer to a specific server and then paste the location into my form. Make sense?

I found some VBS code that will copy a file, and some VBS code that will let me right-click a file to get the location displayed. But I have no idea how to combine them. Any ideas on how to do this?

Copy code:

```
Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.CopyFile "\\file to be copied path", "\\destination directory"
```

Get path code (requires a registry edit to show up in the context menu):

```
set oFso = createObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

if wscript.arguments.count >= 1 then

    strPath = wscript.arguments(0)


    strDriveName = ofso.GetDriveName(strPath)

    set oDrive = ofso.GetDrive(strDriveName)



    Select Case oDrive.DriveType
            Case 0: t = "Unknown"
        Case 1: t = "Removable"
        Case 2: t = "Fixed"
        Case 3: t = "Network"
        Case 4: t = "CD-ROM"
        Case 5: t = "RAM Disk"
    End Select

    strFileName = ofso.GetFileName(strPath)

    test = inputbox("The path is...","Path", strPath)

else

    msgbox "no args"

end if
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will take one argument (the name of a file) and move it to the location defined in `sLocation` at the top of the code. Once done, it'll display a confirmation and place the path to the file (in the new location) in the clipboard for pasting.

As far as I know VBScript has no ability to directly manipulate the clipboard, so we hand this out to the MSDOS `clip` command in order to do this.

```
Option Explicit
' Change sLocation in the line below to the folder you want to move files to.
Dim sLocation : sLocation = "C:\Temp"
Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim wsh : Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Missing a filename!"
    WScript.Quit
End If
If fso.FileExists(WScript.Arguments(0)) = False Then
    MsgBox "File '" & WScript.Arguments(0) & "' doesn't exist!"
    WScript.Quit
End If
Dim oFile : Set oFile = fso.GetFile(WScript.Arguments(0))
fso.CopyFile oFile.Path, sLocation
Dim sNewLocation : sNewLocation = sLocation & "\" & oFile.Name
wsh.Run "cmd.exe /c echo " & sNewLocation & "| clip", 0, True
Msgbox "File moved to " & sNewLocation & VbCrLf & "and new path copied to clipboard."
Set fso = Nothing
Set wsh = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
```

To install, you need to either add a registry key so this script is called when right-clicking on an item or you run the following command `shell:sendto` in order to open up the "Send to" folder and put a shortcut in here to the script. If you do the latter, then you should be able to right click on a file and select the script from the "Send To" menu.

Comment: Love this clip solution!
Most other solutions rely on Internet Explorer, which now prompts the user for access to the clipboard. If you don't show IE, then the script fails silently.
This clip solution works great. :-)